# Помогите проверить код на Пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: Дан список из 30 чисел, которые характеризуют температуру воздуха в ноябре 21 года. Определить, сколько дней температура была выше 5 градусов.

Сам код:

```
print(sum(i > 5 for i in map(int, input().split())))
```

Если не правильно помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: мне кажется, или вы вместо количества дней с заданной температурой, ищете сумму температур дней с заданной температурой?

Comment: @strawdog, вам кажется.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru да я практически уверен. товарищ суммирует градусы, а не дни.

Comment: @strawdog, вы не правы. Практически, значит на практике. Вы запускали? Суммируется True и False.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru вероятно, вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

нормальный код

как вариант (работает чуть побыстрее, поскольку не считается сумма)

```
print(len([i for i in map(int, input().split()) if i > 5]))
```

ну и если изгаляться дальше в одну строку и чтоб покороче, то

```
print(len([i for i in input().split() if int(i) > 5]))
```

ну и ваш код с суммой можно чуть-чуть сократить

```
print(sum(int(i) > 5 for i in input().split()))
```

Comment: А не подскажите как будет выглядеть код в длинном варианте?

Comment: т.е. это не ваш код? короткие варианты приходят после длинных :) - разверните for и будет длинный

Comment: Я очень сильно сейчас обнаглею но вы не можете написать как должен выглядеть вариант с for

Comment: ну вводите счетчик до фора, внутри фора увеличиваете счетчик в зависимости от условия. Неужто вам лень потратить полчаса-час и почитать вступление в учебник по python (первые страниц 10)? https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python - дочитайте до 7 темы

Answer (score -1):

Еще варианты:

```py
print(sum(map((5).__lt__, map(int, input().split()))))
print((*map((5).__lt__, map(int, input().split())),).count(1))
```